# R Data Wrangling: Messy qualifiers

Tags: r

I'm working with some incredibly messy data in the following format:

```
Site Info   Date      Parameter    Result
K1           1/1/12     Nitrogen    14.9
K2           1/1/12     TKN         37.3
K9           2/23/19    Iron        NA
```

The Result column is currently still in character format due to two main problems. First, all of the qualifiers are attached to the data itself in the following manner: "332_Q" or "8.34_J,Q". So, when there's more than one qualifier they are added on after a comma. Second, sometimes there are more than one datum per cell. According to the metadata, these occurred when sampling by two different groups occurred at the same location and same day. The format of the double data is the following: "14.01, 14.06" or "43, NA".

So, I need to separate the double data so that each datum is in own row with the same site data, date, and parameter correct. I also need to remove the qualifiers from the data and place it in it's own new column so I can convert the data into a numeric format for further manipulation. I'm not quite sure how to elegantly accomplish this, especially with the overlap of the double data and multiple qualifier comma use.

Comment: Can you provide some more data for us to work from? This should be pretty easy with `separate_rows`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider this example data:

```
SiteInfo     Date       Parameter   Result
K1           1/1/12     Nitrogen    "14.9_Q, 13.2"
K2           1/1/12     TKN         "37.3, 12.2_J,Q"
K9           2/23/19    Iron        "NA, 13.1"
```

We can use `tidyr` to `separate_rows` and `separate` the qualifiers from the value.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  separate_rows(Result,sep =  ", ") %>%
  separate(Result, into = c("Result", "Qualifier"), sep = "_", convert = TRUE)
  SiteInfo    Date Parameter Result Qualifier
1       K1  1/1/12  Nitrogen   14.9         Q
2       K1  1/1/12  Nitrogen   13.2      <NA>
3       K2  1/1/12       TKN   37.3      <NA>
4       K2  1/1/12       TKN   12.2       J,Q
5       K9 2/23/19      Iron     NA      <NA>
6       K9 2/23/19      Iron   13.1      <NA>
```

The `convert = TRUE` argument will helpfully change result into  numeric from character.